# Send data to Tableview Embedded inside a container embedded inside a UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UISplitViewController` that contains the following setup:

```
MasterTableViewController - > UINavigationController -> CustomViewController -> Container -> CustomTableViewController
```

I am able to send data from the `MasterTableViewController` to the `CustomViewController` via a segue like this:

```
if segue.identifier == "showCustomView" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let section = self.survey[indexPath.row]
                let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! CustomViewController

                controller.detailItem = section

                if let work = workItem{
                controller.workItem = work
                }

            }
        }
```

I don't know however how to send that same data through to the `CustomTableViewController`, can it be done from the `MasterViewController` or do I first have get the data and then send it on via my `CustomViewController`

The ultimate goal here is to get an `NSManagedObject` through to the `CustomTableViewController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CustomViewController` is in charge with forwarding that data to its views and therefore to ViewControllers of embedded Views in Containers. For doing so you may want to add a new "setter" to `CustomViewController` and in your code sniplet cast to `CustomViewController` instead of `UINavigationController` and pass that value. This setter then should forward the data to the sub-view controller and/or pass it within `viewDidLoad`. Be aware that you cannot fully control whether the setter is called first or `viewDidLoad` was called first when working with storyboards. Therefore do proper nil checks and implement setting the property of the sub-view controller in both methods.

Comment: Thank you kindly for the response, do you have a worked example?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any code example hany. But this is pretty much straight forward. The only catch is that you never really know which comes first, viewDidLoad or the setter. When the setter comes first then the reference to the UI item (in your case the container) is nil and when the view is created first then the property, that you want to set, is nil. Meaning you call the setter of the subview from both methods only, when the view and the property are not nil. However, in 99,9% the setter whould be invoked first when called in `prepareForSegue`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using the embed segue identifier I had set in the storyboard linking the `container` and the `CustomTableViewController`:

This is the code on the `CustomViewController`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue,
        sender: AnyObject?) {

           if segue.identifier == "embedSegueIdentifier"{
                if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? CustomTableViewController
                     {

                        self.embeddedViewController = vc
                        self.embeddedViewController.workItem = work

                }


            }
}
```